# How to I make my form (in grid format) reactive in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I created this form in bootstrap 5, which contains 1 row with 4 columns (1 dropdown menu and 3 buttons). It is properly formatted o my desktop, however when I run the page on a mobile device, the buttons shrink and stay on one row, instead of flexing to fit the new resolution. How should I structure the form so that when the webpage is run on mobile, the buttons stack on top of each other instead of beside each other?

[Picture of my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPUja.png)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row g-3 mx-3">
            <div class="col">
                <select class="form-select form-control">
                    <option selected>Select Level</option>
                    <option value="1">Easy</option>
                    <option value="2">Medium</option>
                    <option value="3">Hard</option>
                    <option value="4">Evil</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">New Board</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-danger">Clear Board</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success">Check</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: See this part of the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/#stacked-to-horizontal

Answer (score 3):

You should set class as `col-md-3 col-sm-12`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row g-3 mx-3">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <select class="form-select form-control">
          <option selected>Select Level</option>
          <option value="1">Easy</option>
          <option value="2">Medium</option>
          <option value="3">Hard</option>
          <option value="4">Evil</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">New Board</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-danger">Clear Board</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success">Check</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! the solution works for narrow windows on my desktop however it still shows the 4 buttons in a row when I view it through a mobile viewport (selecting a mobile view when inspecting the element. I added a picture to my original post for context

Comment: You should use responsive column class with `sm`, `md`, `lg`